# Is there a way to programatically set the user profile picture on Windows 8?

Tags: c#, powershell, windows-8

The only information I can find is this undocumented method in shell32.dll, which applies to Windows 7 only:

```
[DllImport("shell32.dll", EntryPoint = "#262", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, PreserveSig = false)]
public static extern void SetUserTile(string username, int whatever, string picpath);
```

Is there a way (PowerShell, C#, command line etc.) to programmatically set the user picture of a **Local Account** (i.e. not Active Directory account, not Microsoft account) on the login page of Windows 8?

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure i've come across this before and the solution was to copy the desired photo to the following location, the picture must be named user.bmp and it has to be a 128x128, 24-bit bitmap picture.

%ProgramData%\Microsoft\User Account Pictures\